# segmentation fault on clicking a GtkButton

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Depending on the location of the `init_prog(user)` call in my program I get a segmentation fault, I don't understand the reason. If I put the call in the `start()` callback function after clicking `btn_go` it crashes:

`Thread 1 "./a.out" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7812526 in gdk_window_get_display (window=0x55555555b1c0) at ../../../../gdk/gdkwindow.c:2303
2303    ../../../../gdk/gdkwindow.c: No such file or directory.`

This is the back trace:

```
Thread 1 "./a.out" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7812526 in gdk_window_get_display (window=0x55555555b1c0) at ../../../../gdk/gdkwindow.c:2303
2303    ../../../../gdk/gdkwindow.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7812526 in gdk_window_get_display (window=0x55555555b1c0) at ../../../../gdk/gdkwindow.c:2303
#1  0x00007ffff78022ce in event_get_display (event=0x7fffe800add0) at ../../../../gdk/gdkevents.c:457
#2  0x00007ffff78022ce in gdk_event_free (event=0x7fffe800add0) at ../../../../gdk/gdkevents.c:839
#3  0x00007ffff783311a in gdk_event_source_dispatch
    (source=<optimized out>, callback=<optimized out>, user_data=<optimized out>)
    at ../../../../../gdk/x11/gdkeventsource.c:369
#4  0x00007ffff730cf2e in g_main_context_dispatch () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff730d1c8 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff730d4c2 in g_main_loop_run () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff7affb15 in gtk_main () at ../../../../gtk/gtkmain.c:1323
#8  0x0000555555556da1 in create_window () at gui.c:118
#9  0x000055555555644d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe328) at main.c:26
```

This is the code:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void start (GtkWidget *widget, struct prog_data *user);

void create_window() {

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *headbar;
    GtkWidget *vbox;
    GtkWidget *hbox_superself;
    GtkWidget *hbox_my_struct;
    GtkWidget *hbox_self;
    GtkWidget *btn_about;
    GtkWidget *btn_go;
    GtkWidget *evnt_box[3];

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    headbar = gtk_header_bar_new();
    btn_about = gtk_button_new_with_label("About");
    btn_go = gtk_button_new_with_label("Start");
    evnt_box[0] = gtk_evnt_box_new ();
    evnt_box[1] = gtk_evnt_box_new ();
    evnt_box[2] = gtk_evnt_box_new ();
    vbox = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    hbox_superself = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 35);
    hbox_my_struct = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    hbox_self = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 35);
    my_struct.label_user[USR0] = gtk_label_new ("0");
    my_struct.label_user[USR1] = gtk_label_new ("0");
    my_struct.lbl_pings_left = gtk_label_new ("");

    my_struct.img_show[0] = gtk_image_new ();
    my_struct.img_show[1] = gtk_image_new ();

    my_struct.image_deck_pile = gtk_image_new_from_file ("1.png");

my_struct.self_image[0] = gtk_image_new_from_file ("2.png");
my_struct.self_image[1] = gtk_image_new_from_file ("2.png");
my_struct.self_image[2] = gtk_image_new_from_file ("2.png");

    my_struct.image_orca = gtk_image_new ();

    my_struct.super_self[0] = gtk_image_new();
    my_struct.super_self[1] = gtk_image_new();
    my_struct.super_self[2] = gtk_image_new();

    gtk_header_bar_set_title (GTK_HEADER_BAR (headbar), "Orca");
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Orca");    
    gtk_window_set_titlebar (GTK_WINDOW (window), headbar);
    gtk_header_bar_set_show_close_button (GTK_HEADER_BAR (headbar), TRUE);
    gtk_window_maximize (GTK_WINDOW (window));

    GtkCssProvider *css_provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path (css_provider, "style.css", NULL);

    GdkScreen *myScreen = gdk_screen_get_default();
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (myScreen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (css_provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);

    struct prog_data user[2];

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (headbar), btn_about);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), hbox_superself);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), hbox_my_struct);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), hbox_self);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_superself), my_struct.self_image[0]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_superself), my_struct.self_image[1]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_superself), my_struct.self_image[2]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_superself), my_struct.label_user[USR1]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_my_struct), my_struct.image_orca);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_my_struct), my_struct.image_deck_pile);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_my_struct), my_struct.lbl_pings_left);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_my_struct), btn_go);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_my_struct), my_struct.img_show[0]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_my_struct), my_struct.img_show[1]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_self), evnt_box[0]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_self), evnt_box[1]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_self), evnt_box[2]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (evnt_box[0]), my_struct.super_self[0]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (evnt_box[1]), my_struct.super_self[1]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (evnt_box[2]), my_struct.super_self[2]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_self), my_struct.label_user[USR0]);

    GtkStyleContext *context1;                                      
    context1 = gtk_widget_get_style_context(hbox_self);         
    gtk_style_context_add_class(context1, "my_hbox_self");

    GtkStyleContext *context2;
    context2 = gtk_widget_get_style_context(hbox_superself);    
    gtk_style_context_add_class(context2, "my_hbox_superself");

    GtkStyleContext *context3;
    context3 = gtk_widget_get_style_context(hbox_my_struct);    
    gtk_style_context_add_class(context3, "my_hbox_my_struct");

    gtk_widget_set_name (my_struct.img_show[0], "user1");

    g_signal_connect (btn_about, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (activate_about), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (evnt_box[0]), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK (ping1_clicked), user);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (evnt_box[1]), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK (ping2_clicked), user);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (evnt_box[2]), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK (ping3_clicked), user);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (btn_go), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK (start), user);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main();
}

void start (GtkWidget *btn_go, struct prog_data *user) {
    gtk_widget_hide(btn_go);
    printf("Right\n");
    init_prog(user);    
}
```

If I move the call `init_prog(user)` in the `create_window()` function after `gtk_widget_show_all (window);`, I do not experience any crash. I've tested the `init_prot(user)` function separately and it works well.

Comment: Where is the definition of init_prog()? Where is the definition of my_struct?

Comment: I keep separate the gui and the c part. The definition is in another .c file: `void init_pro(struct prog_data *user);`

Comment: Please provide us something to can compile.

Comment: You should always provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code is not minimal and not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cheating GTK by providing an incorrect callback function.

[The manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event) tells us how your callback shall look like for `"button_press_event"`:

```
gboolean
user_function (GtkWidget *widget,
               GdkEvent  *event,
               gpointer   user_data)
```

You access `event` pointer and treat is as `user_data` pointer. That causes undefined behaviour.
You also fail to provide mandatory boolean return value.

You must adjust the signature of your callback function to match the requirements.

Or maybe you might change to use `"clicked"` or `"pressed"` event of the button widget instead of the `"button-pressed-event"`.

You also should check the other callback functions that were not present in the question for the same error.